# Android, How to create Context Menu...

Tags: android, android-menu

Here i wrote some code but not getting output..
Please tell me why is not displaying that context menu, where am i doing mistake...?
Please guide me, Thanks in Advance....

more_tab_menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:id="@+id/feeds"
    android:title="Feeds"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/friends"
    android:title="Friends"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/about"
    android:title="About"/>
</menu>
```

MenuTest.java

```
public class MenuTest extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}

@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
        ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    MenuInflater inflater =getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.more_tab_menu, menu);
}
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    AdapterContextMenuInfo contextMenuInfo=(AdapterContextMenuInfo)item.getMenuInfo();
    switch(item.getItemId())
    {
    case R.id.feeds:
        break;
    case R.id.friends:
        break;
    case R.id.about:
        break;
    }

    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Please tell me where am i doing mistake...?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Right now you have this:

```
super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
MenuInflater inflater =getMenuInflater();
inflater.inflate(R.menu.more_tab_menu, menu);
```

Change it to this:

```
MenuInflater inflater =getMenuInflater();
inflater.inflate(R.menu.more_tab_menu, menu);
return true;
```

Also in onOptionsItemSelected:

```
return true;
```

Also use onCreateOptionsMenu and onOptionsItemSelected.

Comment: sorry, i posted something wrong in the post.. i changed it. try now

Comment: onCreateContextMenu()'s method return type is void then how can we return boolean, it will generate compile time error.

Comment: use onCreateOptionsMenu and onOptionsItemSelected

Answer (score 3):

You need to register your menu with [registerForContextMenu](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#registerForContextMenu%28android.view.View%29).

From [this page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#context-menu)

> In order for a View to provide a
>   context menu, you must "register" the
>   view for a context menu. Call
>   registerForContextMenu() and pass it
>   the View you want to give a context
>   menu. When this View then receives a
>   long-press, it displays a context
>   menu.

Your code above works just fine. You just need to register the content menu to a view.

If you want to launch the context menu from anywhere in the screen:

Let's say your layout `main.xml` is like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

</LinearLayout>
```

You will register the context menu you have created with the following (in `onCreate`):

```
 LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
 registerForContextMenu(layout);
```

So if you run this in the emulator, and do a long-click on the Android desktop, your menu will pop up.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this:

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);

    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.more_tab_menu, menu);
}
```

With this:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.more_tab_menu, menu);

    return true;
}
```

This will result in the menu items being displayed when the Menu button on the phone is pressed.

Comment: Not available method in `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`